# Computing the unit vectors of high-dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I want to compute the unit vectors of a high-dimensional matrix.

```
eig_vectors=(eig_vectors/sqrt(eig_vectors'*eig_vectors));


K>> size(eig_vectors)

ans =

         400      153600
```

It runs into memory issues due to `eig_vectors'*eig_vectors`. What is a fast way to achieve it?

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking to sort out memory issue and ask how to resolve it rather than jumping onto making it faster?

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the reply! Yeah, memory issue is the first priority.

Comment: So, please make the question specific. As it stands, its too-broad.

Comment: Are you sure that your formula for the norm is correct? Am I right in the assumption that you would like to divide each vector by its 2-norm?

Comment: @Jonas Oh! yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the norm by directly summing the squares of the matrix elements, thus avoiding the large matrix multiplication.

```
eig_vectors = bsxfun(@rdivide,eig_vectors,sqrt(sum(eig_vectors.^2,2)))
```

If that's still a memory issue for you, you can always go with a loop

```
   for iVector = 1:size(eig_vectors,1)
        eig_vectors(iVector,:) = eig_vectors(iVector,:)./norm(eig_vectors(iVector,:));
   end
```

Comment: The code produces different numbers than the code in the question.

Comment: @Daniel: Indeed it does. For the moment, I will assume that OP wanted to divide each vector by its 2-norm, and made a mistake in their code :)